# Problem in understanding the derivatives of functions defined implicitly

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> **Problem**
>   Suppose there is a surface $F(x,y,z)=0$. Also $z=f(x,y)$. Substituting $z$ we get 
>   $F(x,y,f(x,y))=0$ for all $(x,y)$ in some open set $S$. Now we introduce an auxiliary function $g$ defined on $S$ as follows:
>   $$
> g(x,y)= F(x,y,f(x,y)).
> $$
>   So $g(x,y)=0$ on $S$. Hence *partial derivatives of $g$ are also zero*.
>
> (From Apostal Calculus volume 2)

I am not able to understand the last line. If the partial derivatives are zero, the gradient is always zero, which is not the case. For example let $F(u,v)$, where $u=xy$ and $v=(x^2+z^2)^{1/2}$. Partial derivatives exist at $(1,1,3)$.

Comment: The partial derivatives are zero on $S$, because $g$ is constant on $S$.

Comment: Actually, Apostol's language (if you are quoting him precisely) is sloppy. $g$ is a function of $(x,y)$, nothing to do with $S$. Your example isn't an example. Take $F(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2-1$ and $z=f(x,y) = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ [for $x^2+y^2<1$, say]. Then the auxiliary function $g(x,y) = F(x,y,f(x,y)) = x^2+y^2+(\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})^2 - 1 = 0$ for all $x,y$ with $x^2+y^2<1$.